# How do I get the name of the current executable in C#?

Tags: c#, command-line

I want to get the name of the currently running program, that is the executable name of the program. In C/C++ you get it from `args[0]`.

Comment: Executable is EXE file (Windows Forms, WPF applications) ? A program can be a Desktop App (WinForms, WPF; and WinRT-Windows Phone?), Web Application, Wcf Service Application, Visual Studio Addin, Outlook-Word Addin, Unit Test in VS (MSTest), or, Silverlight Application.

Answer (score 464, accepted):

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName
```

Comment: Beware of accepted answer. We've had issues with using `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName` under Click-Once deployed applications. For us, this is returning "*DefaultDomain*", and not the original exe name.

Comment: @Gaspode thanks for the heads up! So how did you get around this?

Comment: We used this in the end: `string file = object_of_type_in_application_assembly.GetType().Assembly.Location; string app = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( file ); `

Comment: FriendlyName can be set to anything. Also getting the assembly location may not be enough if you have an exe with several dlls. Furthermore if you use several AppDomain, Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() returns null.

Comment: @Gaspode : it would be easier just to say Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(GetType().Assembly.Location) - you don't need to specify an object of a type in the current assembly. You can use GetType of this, and then you don't even need to say "this."

Comment: friendly name returned by this call gives me 

C:\Users\root\AppData\Roaming\myapp.vshost.exe

vshost.exe part is hardly something that I wanted to get back...

Comment: @Califf: that looks like the VS debugging .exe host name; are you running a debug version, perhaps through visual studio?

Comment: @Steven I would prefer to use something that returns a consistent name  in both Debug and Release modes, for example if is to be used to create a data profile name for the app in user's directory. So far, the Lee Grissom's answer satisfies this requirement. Sorry I somehow missed it last time.

Comment: Not the same ProcessName, FriendlyName, ModuleName and ApplicationName  (AppDomain.CurrentDomain, Process, Process.MainModule).

              

ProcessName: vstest.executionengine.x86
ConfigurationFile: C:\TFS\Tests\bin\Debug\Tests.v4.0.dll.config
MainModule.FileName: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe
MainModule.ModuleName: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe
BaseDirectory: C:\TFS\Tests\bin\Debug
ApplicationBase: C:\TFS\Tests\bin\Debug
FriendlyName: UnitTestAdapter: Running test
ApplicationName:

Comment: This property can return unexpected values. I've used it in unit test and it has "UnitTestAdapter: Running test" value (which is not valid filename)

Comment: @vbullinger : true, it's just that in the case we used it the code was not in the exe but an associated assembly.

Comment: @Gaspode, What is the issue you had with "with using System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName under Click-Once deployed applications"? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank, "For us, this is returning "DefaultDomain", and not the original exe name."  I'm not sure what more you want to know.

Comment: This can be useful, but it should **not** be the accepted answer: It is vastly different from what was asked for - it will coincidentally be the same thing in *some* situations, but this is something else entirely. If you didn't write the application yourself it could very well return "I like potatoes!" or whatever else your humorous colleague wrote into this property when they built the application!

Comment: System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.Substring(0,System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.IndexOf(".")) - because I need name without extension

Comment: Is it possible to have that information as a constant expression? I'd like to it in a decorator.

Comment: @Tristan No. It's not constant. (It has to be evaluated at run time.)

Answer (score 331):

[`System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.friendlyname.aspx) - Returns the filename with extension (e.g. MyApp.exe).

[`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processname.aspx) - Returns the filename *without* extension (e.g. MyApp).

[`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.modulename.aspx) - Returns the full path and filename (e.g. C:\Examples\Processes\MyApp.exe).  You could then pass this into `System.IO.Path.GetFileName()` or `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` to achieve the same results as the above.

Comment: AppDomain can be a EXE application, Web application, Unit test application, Addin Visual Studio, and "Silverlight App"(?). Maybe interesting full solution for all cases. For example, for Unit Test VS2012 -              

ProcessName: vstest.executionengine.x86
MainModule.FileName: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe
MainModule.ModuleName: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe
FriendlyName: UnitTestAdapter: Running test
ApplicationName:

Comment: A "program" can be a Desktop App (WinForms, WPF; and WinRT-Windows Phone?), Web Application, Wcf Service Application, Visual Studio Addin, Outlook-Word Addin, Unit Test in VS (MSTest), or, Silverlight Application. For example, how get service Host assembly for a Wcf Service Application hosted in IIS, not IISExpress or WebDevServer ?

Comment: +1 I’m going to go with this answer because it provides all three variations that you might need in a clean and simple way. Using the bare program name without path or extension is very useful for in-program help text (`/?` switch), because using the extension and path just clutter it unnecessarily.

Comment: Remember to dispose the result of `GetCurrentProcess()`

Comment: `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName()` returns *MyApp.vshost* for me.

Comment: Under Mono on Linux, `Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName` returned `/usr/bin/mono-sgen`. The `GetType().Assembly.Location` approach returned the desired executable path for both Linux and Windows.

Comment: With Mono runtime at least "System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName" works but "System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName" does not FYI.

Answer (score 121):

This should suffice:

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
```

Comment: Hmm, this returns (when run from vs.net and using the debug hosting thing), the location and name of the filename.vshost.exe ...  that is indeed the file that is executing at this time )

Comment: This the best answer for me because `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` is the exact C# analogue of `argv` from C/C++.

Comment: Agreed! best answer. I have a need to get Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1];

Comment: Works on Mono/Linux. The returned string is the full path to the exe running without the "mono " part that would be really bothersome if present. As said before this is exact analogue of C/C++ main function argv parameter.

Comment: To avoid full path: `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0])`

Comment: This won't always supply the full path, as opposed to `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName`

Comment: If you copy the executable and run the two copies with different names, this returns only the most recently started executable in the AppDomain. Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName does not have this static problem,

Comment: If the exe is started without ".exe" (e.g. from command line), this solution will give the executable name without ".exe".

Comment: This works well when trying to track down WCF services.  The process name comes back with iisexpress in my case.  But this command gives me the actual WCF service assembly name.

Comment: When using .NET 6+ use: `Environment.ProcessPath`   (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processpath )

Answer (score 116):

`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()` gets the currently running process. You can use the [`ProcessName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.processname.aspx) property to figure out the name. Below is a sample console app.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Better use Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName

Comment: Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName works perfectly from within an Excel Addin (ExcelDNA)

Comment: This approach will fail when used on the Mono runtime; the process name for applications running on Mono will always be some variant of `.../bin/mono` on *nixes or `.../mono.exe` on Windows.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Current AppDomain name may have nothing to do with executable process name, especially when multiple app domains are present

Comment: This method can be substantially slower than playing with the Assembly class.

Comment: @cdhowie, Could you recover the entire process invocation string such as :"/usr/bin/mono/mono /home/richard/test/foo.exe" ? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank Perhaps using OS-specific tricks, such as reading `/proc/self/cmdline`. (`var args = File.ReadAllText("/proc/self/cmdline").Split('\0'); args = args.Take(args.Length - 1).ToArray();` would give you an array of such arguments.)

Comment: @Frank `Environment.CommandLine` *should* be the invocation string. Could be that mono filters itself out from it - or not - I haven't tested it on a linux machine myself so you would have to test it yourself. (I think it *does* filter away the mono-part since some applications could have behavior that depends on this property - and they probably wont be expecting it to be prefixed by mono "stuff".)

Comment: Fails in .NET Core - "dotnet.exe" - (as well as Mono, for the same / similar reason).

Answer (score 21):

This is the code which worked for me:

```
string fullName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
string myName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullName);
```

All the examples above gave me the processName with vshost or the running dll name.

Comment: For those that dont know, or missed it in other answers, the namespace for Assembly is System.Reflection, and the namespace for Path is System.IO.

Comment: GetEntryAssembly will return null if the application entry point is in native code rather than an assembly.

Comment: Beware this crashes with .net 5 and single file assemblies

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```

This returns you a [`System.Reflection.Assembly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly) instance that has all the data you could ever want to know about the current application.  I think that the [`Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location) property might get what you are after specifically.

Comment: It might be safer to use `CodeBase` instead of `Location` in case .NET's shadow copy feature is active. See http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/06/26/assembly-codebase-vs-assembly-location.aspx

Comment: Beware of GetExecutingAssembly(): if you call this from a library assembly, it returns the name of the library assembly, which is different from the name of the entry assembly (i.e. the original executable). If you use GetEntryAssembly(), it returns the name of the actual executable, but it throws an exception if the process is running under WCF (admittedly a rare situation). For the most robust code, use Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName.

Comment: @Gravitas: Certainly not, any executable that is running "interpreted", e.g. with /usr/bin/mono will have the wrong process name. Also ProcessName won't work with windows services. If you use it in a library, use GetCallingAssembly.

Comment: Worked for me. The property Name of the returned Assembly instance GetName() call is what you need, and does not include the ".exe" part. Also tested on Mono/Linux with expected result. Assembly.GetName().Name

Comment: Hmm, note that the returned string won't change even if you rename the executable file by hand using the file explorer. While Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0] changes along with the actual executable filename (of course). Coincidentally, the second method resulted better for my specific situation as I want the data folder to be named as the actual executable filename.

Answer (score 12):

Why nobody suggested this, its simple.

```
Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath)
```

Comment: Which namespace does Application resides.

Comment: This is useful when inside a Windows Forms app, but not otherwise

Comment: @NineBerry You might be interested in `Application.ExecutablePath`'s [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,351).

Comment: @NineBerry See my post. This works within Console apps if you add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.

Answer (score 11):

Couple more options:

- `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name`
- `Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616584/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-executable-in-c#comment4394906_616588

Answer (score 11):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.Name;
```

will give you FileName of your app like; "MyApplication.exe"

Answer (score 10):

If you need the Program name to set up a firewall rule, use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

This will ensure that the name is correct both when debugging in VisualStudio and when running the app directly in windows.

Comment: For my purposes (creating a logging filename), this is the best answer.   If running a hosted process (say, a service, or a web application), System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName can return an ugly GUID-y  name with embedded slashes.

Comment: This does *not* work for .NET Core 2+, which will report "dotnet.exe" - or perhaps the apphost if setup as such.

Answer (score 9):

When uncertain or in doubt, run in circles, scream and shout.

```
class Ourself
{
    public static string OurFileName() {
        System.Reflection.Assembly _objParentAssembly;

        if (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() == null)
            _objParentAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        else
            _objParentAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

        if (_objParentAssembly.CodeBase.StartsWith("http://"))
            throw new System.IO.IOException("Deployed from URL");

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(_objParentAssembly.Location))
            return _objParentAssembly.Location;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName))
            return System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

        throw new System.IO.IOException("Assembly not found");
    }
}
```

I can't claim to have tested each option, but it doesn't do anything stupid like returning the vhost during debugging sessions.

Comment: +1 for amusement. :-) I would hardly use this code, though, unless I'm writing a really generic library that has no idea about its environment (and then it probably wouldn't be a good idea to maintain whatever global state you were going to use the name for).

Comment: @Orwellophile A "program" can be a Desktop App (WinForms, WPF; and WinRT-Windows Phone?), Web Application, Wcf Service Application, Visual Studio Addin, Outlook-Word Addin, Unit Test in VS (MSTest), or, Silverlight Application. For example, how get service Host assembly for a Wcf Service Application hosted in IIS, not IISExpress or WebDevServer ? Any full code valid for A WinForms, WPF, Web Application, Wcf Service Application, Visual Studio Addin, Outlook-Word Addin, Unit Test in VS (MSTest) applications ?

Answer (score 8):

- `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` returns location of exe name if assembly is not loaded from memory.
- `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase` returns location as URL.

Comment: Tested, this works 100%, even if its called from within a C# library.

Comment: GetEntryAssembly() returns null if you're not in the main AppDomain.

Answer (score 6):

If you are publishing a single file application in .NET 6.0 or above, you can use [Environment.ProcessPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processpath?view=net-6.0#System_Environment_ProcessPath)

Comment: For current WPF (as of 2023), this delivers the expected EXE name. All the others return the created DLL which is slightly different from what I want (the exe). Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This works if you need only the application name without extension:

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs.aspx) to obtain the arguments and [`Environment.CommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx) to obtain the actual command line as entered.

Also, you can use [`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx) or [`Process.GetCurrentProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx).

However, when debugging, you should be careful as this final example may give your debugger's executable name (depending on how you attach the debugger) rather than your executable, as may the other examples.

Comment: Beware of GetExecutingAssembly(): if you call this from a library assembly, it returns the name of the library assembly, which is different from the name of the entry assembly (i.e. the original executable). If you use GetEntryAssembly(), it returns the name of the actual executable, but it throws an exception if the process is running under WCF (admittedly a rare situation). For the most robust code, use Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName.

Comment: @Gravitas: good point - wow, it's been a while since I wrote this! :D I'll edit accordingly

Comment: `Environment.CommandLine` gives the absolute path, not the entered command line, at least on Mono/Linux.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: Sounds like Mono doesn't quite follow the documentation. Interesting.

Answer (score 3):

IF you are looking for the full path information of your executable, the reliable way to do it is to use the following:

```
   var executable = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule
                       .FileName.Replace(".vshost", "");
```

This eliminates any issues with intermediary dlls, vshost, etc.

Comment: I tried your reliable way in Ubuntu Linux 15.10 C++ using realpath followed by STL C++ string replace and it caused Point and Click to fail. Could that have been caused by a bug in  mono as our director of software surmised today? Thanks.

Comment: I don't program on Mono, though it might be fun to try

Comment: Gasponde wrote above that "We've had issues with using System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName under Click-Once deployed applications." Could you make a guess as to what the issues might be with Click-Once deployed applications in .NET? Thanks.

Comment: Returns C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe for my Sample program in VS2017.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ().Location
```

Comment: Beware of GetExecutingAssembly(): if you call this from a library assembly, it returns the name of the library assembly, which is different from the name of the entry assembly (i.e. the original executable). If you use GetEntryAssembly(), it returns the name of the actual executable, but it throws an exception if the process is running under WCF (admittedly a rare situation). For the most robust code, use Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName.

Comment: An answer should not be a question.  Is that what the OP wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Super easy, here:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName
```

Comment: For .NET Core Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName returns "dotnet".

Comment: The current directory is temporally transient and cannot be relied on to be the location of the assembly/executable.

Answer (score 1):

On .Net Core (or Mono), most of the answers won't apply when the binary defining the process is the runtime binary of Mono or .Net Core (dotnet) and not your actual application you're interested in. In that case, use this:

```
var myName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

Comment: `GetEntryAssembly()` can return null.

Answer (score 0):

For windows apps (forms and console) I use this:

Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms in VS then:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace whatever
{
    class Program
    {
        static string ApplicationName = Application.ProductName.ToString();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ........
        }
    }
}
```

This works correctly for me whether I am running the actual executable or debugging within VS.

Note that it returns the application name without the extension.

John

Answer (score -2):

To get the path and the name

System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName

Comment: This duplicates [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5120157/150605) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36944210/150605).