# Get Correct folder using c#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

so, i am building a new WinForms with update my program.

the thing is, i am not installing any-thing. so,when i give my freinds my program, that can put it where ever they want. how can i know where did they put it?

like, lets say my program called "MyProg".

so lets say my freind puted "MyProg" in C:\programs\install\SayHello.

and i want my program to know where she is and save it to xml(everytimes she loads).

so, i know how to use everything here, i just need to know how can i get the folder path i am in now. (for my explined the foldepath = "C:\programs\install\SayHello.")

Anyone?

Thanks again,
Alon. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the application's path in .NET in a console app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-net-in-a-console-app)

Comment: The linked answer doesn't work for ClickOnce: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616584/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-executable-in-c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [How do I get the name of the current executable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616584/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-executable-in-c), to find the name of the currently running assembly:

`string file = object_of_type_in_application_assembly.GetType().Assembly.Location; 
  string app = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);`

so to find the path of the currently running assembly

`string file = object_of_type_in_application_assembly.GetType().Assembly.Location; 
  string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(file);`

should do the job.

`Environment.CurrentDirectory` won't necessarily return what you want, as it's possible to run the program from a different folder at the console.

Comment: Or more simply, use System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options, including:

```
Application.ExecutablePath
```

Search for "get exe location c#" for more variations on this.

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.CurrentDirectory` contains the current directory.

Comment: This is the "Start In" path used in shortcuts, and may not necessarily be where executable resides.

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.StartupPath
```

should do the same in your case.

Comment: According to the other answer using assemblies, this would be probably better: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location

Comment: This is the "Start In" path used in shortcuts, and may not necessarily be where executable resides.