# How to get the name of current application in C#

Tags: c#, process

How does one get the current application that is running on window in C#?

Answer (score 10):

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName
```

or maybe

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
```

or if you mean that you want the name of the active window then you should look at;

[How do I get the title of the current active window using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115868/how-do-i-get-the-title-of-the-current-active-window-using-c)

Comment: Do you mean you want the name of the currently active window? If so see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115868/how-do-i-get-the-title-of-the-current-active-window-using-c

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Assembly.FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.fullname.aspx)

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName;
```

Please also take a look at this question:

[How do I get the name of the current executable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616584/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-executable-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, If you have used GetWindowThreadProcessId.

```
public String GetActiveFileNameTitle()
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
        uint procId = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out procId);
        var proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)procId);
        if (proc != null)
        {
           return proc.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.ProductName;
        }

    }
```