# File.ReadLines path relative to application executable?

Tags: c#, file, filepath, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm reading and writing to some text files and I'm currently using a set path. How can I change that set path to use the same folder where the executable resides?

For example:

```
File.ReadLines(@"D:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\MyApplication\names.txt").Skip(1).ToList();
```

and...

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\MyApplication\names.txt", lines);
```

and...

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\MyApplication\names.txt", true))
{
    writer.WriteLine(myText);
}
```

It also needs to work when testing in the IDE (Visual Studio).

Comment: Just use the file name. The working directory is always the executable directory.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: That is not true at all. If you run "c:\foo\program.exe" from some other directory, the current working directory will be the directory you're in, *not* "c:\foo\".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path is relative to the current working directory. When running in the IDE, that will be the directory in which the executable resides. Otherwise it's typically the directory in which you started the program.

So if your current directory (on the command line) is C:\foo and you enter the command "C:\bar\myprogram.exe", your program will start in C:\foo and if you try to open the file "fooby.txt", it will look for "C:\foo\fooby.txt".

See [How do I get the name of the current executable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/616584/56778) for information about how to get the executable file path.

Answer (score 1):

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

If you're in winforms app you may use

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath
```

By default it will be pointed to the current directory as @JimMischel said.

So better avoid just using filenames like this `File.ReadLines("names.txt");` instead provide full file path.

Comment: `File.ReadLines("names.txt")` will not necessarily read from the directory that contains the .exe. It will read from the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` to get the current application folder
Check the [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details

Comment: CurrentDirectory is different check Jim's answer