# Killing all older instances of a program even if program filename is renamed

Tags: vb.net

I have a project called `Test` which is a Form with 1 button. I want to make it so that when I click on the button it kills all the older instances of it.

So here's what I did:

```
Private Sub removeOldInstances()
        'gets all processes with the same name as the project.
        Dim oldProcess() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Test")
        Dim currentProcessId As Integer = Process.GetCurrentProcess.Id
        For Each p As Process In oldProcess
            If p.Id <> currentProcessId Then
                p.Kill()
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

And I made the button call that on click.

So I tested it and it works fine. But the problem occurs when I renamed the .exe to something else and tried to run it. So lets say I renamed it to `Test1` instead of `Test`. If I run 2 instances of it and from one of them if I click the button it won't kill the older instance of it. This is probably because in my `removeOldInstances` method, it gets processes by the name `"Test"`.

I noticed that if you look at the properties of the program, under the details tab is has something called `original filename`. I was thinking maybe I can get all the processes using that, but how would I do that?

If anyone could give a hint or another way of doing this that would be really appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the name of the current executable in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/616584/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-executable-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original Filename is a "VerInfo" property which will not be present as a property in the process. It's something that you can set to whatever you want either when you build your application or using something like [ResHack](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/). You would need to find the file on disk in order to query that information though.

Consider using something like a named mutex with the process ID that your app creates on startup. e.g. On app start, create a named mutex with "myTestAppNamePid1234", and in your process checking loop try to open mutexes with that name and PID you're looping over.