# Resource can not be loaded IF program.exe name changed after compiling

Tags: c#

I have an unmanaged dll so i wrote this to save the dll to file once the program is run.

Working code :

```
public static void ExtractResourceToFile()
{
    if (!File.Exists("loader.dll"))
        try
        {

            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("loader.dll", System.IO.FileMode.Create))
                System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Kraken.Resources.loader.dll").CopyTo(fs);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);

        }       
        catch ( Exception ex)
        { }
}
```

**Problem:**

if the compiled Kraken.exe name changed the DLL is not being saved.

what I've tried :

```
public static void ExtractResourceToFile()
{
    if (!File.Exists("loader.dll"))
        try
        {
            string file = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;;
            string app = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(file, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
                System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(app + ".Resources.loader.dll").CopyTo(fs);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);

        }       
        catch ( Exception ex)
        { }
}
```

I've also tried to get the current process name and use it, but same problem occurred.

Comment: So you ignore the exceptions thrown then wonder why it does not work?

Comment: Set the final file name when you compile so you don't have to change it afterward. If you change it afterward, I think that some information in file properties still have the original name so it would look less professional.

Comment: So you expect `GetManifestResourceStream("foo")` and `GetManifestResourceStream("bar")` to consistently return stream you *want* irrespective of what arguments you pass to the method? Note that there is no direct relationship between name of assembly and default namespace....

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i didnt understand you well, but thats what i mean, GetManifestResourceStream() requires the namespace not the assembly name

Comment: Do `Namespace.Properties.Resources.Name` useful somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

See this:
[How do I get the name of the current executable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616584/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-the-current-executable-in-c)

Particularly these comments are interesting:

> Beware of GetExecutingAssembly(): if you call this from a library
> assembly, it returns the name of the library assembly, which is
> different from the name of the entry assembly (i.e. the original
> executable). If you use GetEntryAssembly(), it returns the name of the
> actual executable, but it throws an exception if the process is
> running under WCF (admittedly a rare situation). For the most robust
> code, use Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName. – Contango Nov 3
> '10 at 12:01
>
> Hmm, note that the returned string won't change even if you rename
> the executable file by hand using the file explorer. While
> Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0] changes along with the actual
> executable filename (of course). Coincidentally, the second method
> resulted better for my specific situation as I want the data folder to
> be named as the actual executable filename. – Hatoru Hansou Jan 23 '14
> at 2:25

Hatoru's comment seems to support Phil1970's comment, that GetExecutingAssembly() probably use the resource properties found in the assembly instead of the actual file name.

So I'd use

> Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName

as Contango suggested.

And as zerkms said, don't ignore exceptions.

Comment: If you feel that linked answer solves the issue just flag as duplicate... But in reality name of executable has nothing to do with parameter of `GetManifestResourceStream`...

Comment: The comments I found useful aren't in the marked answer of the linked thread. Do I flag as duplicate and leave a comment instead?

Comment: @KCWong i did try with ProcessName, but same problem, the exception im getting is: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @meatball Try to break up the line "System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()"... you want to find out if the NullReferenceException came from GetExecutingAssembly() or GetManifestResourceStream(). You should also try using a debugger, set a breakpoint on the line and step into it.

Comment: @KCWong i ended up using base64 and GZip to load it from the code