# How to get real running process name?

Tags: c#, process, .net-core, .net-standard

In a .NET core console app, I'd like to get the running process name, I used [`ProcessName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.processname?view=netcore-2.0#System_Diagnostics_Process_ProcessName) as the docs say, but it always returns `dotnet` as the process name, not the actual underline dll that is running. Although it is a dll, this is a console app, not a library.

```
Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);
```

output

```
dotnet
```

Comment: What does `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName` return? It is [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/616715/6741868).

Comment: It is the right name I wanted, so this is hold in AppDomain not Process, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT:

For .net core you could use:

```
 System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName
```

or

```
 System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name
```

---

For .NET

For a project with Assmebly Name 'This is my name'

[image]

`Console.WriteLine(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);`

prints `This is my name` as shown below.

[image]

Task Manager displays

```
 [assembly: AssemblyTitle("This is my name Title")]
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is in .NET Core, all apps are started by the dotnet cli, it's not the same like in .NET Framework, where each app is in its own exe.

Comment: I added info about AssemblyTitle

Comment: Would `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name` work for you?