# How to set a title to .net core projects to showing vs2019 attach screen?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, .net-core, visual-studio-debugging

I have multiple projects and they all have to work at the same time. I can not distinguish from each other. How can i add title to projects for attach

[image: vscode 2019 attach to proccess screen]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.title?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: The name of the console window has changed, but nothing on the attach screen

Comment: How did you run your app? Did you check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45229477/4728685)?

Comment: into cmd => dotnet myapp.dll

Comment: @noja, does Pavel's answer helps you handle the issue? Please let us know if it helps or not.

Comment: problem not solved. The answer just changes the title of the console app. That's not the title I mentioned. @PerryQian-MSFT